LED as a flyback for a 3V relay?
I have a 3VDC SPDT relay. I don't have a fly back diode but I do have an LED. Can I use the LED as a fly back diode if it's just a 3V relay?
The relay is a HRS4H-S DC3V.

What's the mA rating of the relay?

What are the current rating and reverse voltage rating of the LED and what is the relay coil current rating? This can't be answered without more details if the LED can handle the situation or not.

Hmmm...I cant really tell. the normally closed terminal is 10A 250V and the Normally open terminal is 6A 250V. Then there are couple of more metrics that say 10A 120VAC and 10A 24VDC. But the relay is  labelled HRS4H-S DC3V

Its your typical normal LED that you usually keep the current at 20mA to avoid destroying it

When the coil drive shuts off, the current which is flowing through the coil will begin flowing through the LED. This will likely exceed the maximum rating of the LED. The current will then decay due to coil resistance and the led Vf. You can probably model that on paper fairly accurately. The problem is that most led datahsheets won't specify what the LED can handle in this scenario.

If you have to use something non-standard, another one of the transistor that you are using to drive the relay (BJT or MOSFET) would be a better choice.

What's the LED part number? Please edit this into your question.

Its your basic "coloured LEDS" that have a potential drop of 1.8V - 2V I think. You know, those very common ones

Closed and reopened BECAUSE the LED used was not specific to the problem but matters in the answer so the 3 good answers provide valuable information to others.

The relay coil is rated 3V with a DC resistance of 25ohms. It will consume 120mA while energized. The part that is missing is the coil inductance.
When the coil switches off, at that moment, there will be 120mA of current flowing through the LED. This isn't necessarily a problem, because that is a peak current for an instant; thereafter, the current decays. How fast it decays depends on the inductance of the coil and the IV characteristics of the LED.
You can certainly do this with a high-power LED that can handle 120mA continuous with no problem at all. You can stack standard LED's in series to absorb more energy. You can consider putting an RC snubber across the coil if you don't have a flyback diode. If you Know how much reverse voltage you can tolerate, as a compromise, you can put an LED in series with a resistor. This will limit the LED current*time product at the expense of higher back EMF voltage spike. May be acceptable.
But without the coil inductance, you can't analytically quantify the dynamics.

LEDs typically have a low maximum reverse voltage (VRRM), often something like 2..2.5 V.
You don't state the part number of your LED. But it will have 3 V reverse across it all of the time your relay is energised. If that 3 V exceeds an LED's VRRM then it will be damaged and unreliable.
A typical LED is not a good candidate for clamping the coil's back emf current, though it would only need to dissipate that power for a short period so it's possible it'd withstand it.
So there's multiple reasons why an LED is not a substitute for a power diode across a coil. The primary reason, though, is because exceeding VRRM damages the LED.

Most small LEDs are rated for an absolute maximum peak current of 100mA.
You would be putting a peak current of about 120mA through the LED, so exceeding the absolute maximum rating. While I actually suspect it would be fine, especially with a red LED, this is a bad thing to do and could lead to unpredictable unreliability.
If you don't mind throwing away a bit of power (90mW), about a 25% increase, if you put a 100Ω resistor in parallel with the coil the peak voltage will not exceed 12V so just about any transistor such as S8050 will be fine (12V+3V = 15V across the transistor). The relay will also drop out more quickly, extending the life. Higher resistor values lead to less wasted power, but are harder on the transistor. If you do this, don't be tempted to use the surplus LED as a coil voltage indicator, because the -12V across the LED will exceed the typical -5V rating).
Alternatively, use another transistor as a 5V-rated diode. by tying base to collector.
